# How to update the attendance calendar table without dynamic SQL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table which contains the following columns empid, month, year, day1, day2, day3, day4...........day31.

I have written a SP to update the attendance every day, once the employee log-in.

```
CREATE PROC PROC_Attendance_update @empid INT, @day INT, @month INT, @year INT 

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @sql_text VARCHAR(8000)

SET @sql_Text = 'UPDATE tblattendance SET DAY'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@day)+'=''P'' WHERE empid = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @empid)+'  AND month = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @month)+' AND Year ='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @year)

EXEC(@sql_text)

END
```

But, I don't want it to be in dynamic sql. I want to re-write it to standard T-sQL code.

I tried by it didn't work.

```
CREATE PROC PROC_Attendance_update @empid INT, @day INT, @month INT, @year INT 

AS

BEGIN

UPDATE tblattendance SET CASE   WHEN @day=1 THEN DAY1 = 'P'

                WHEN @day=2 THEN DAY2 = 'P'

                .

                .

                WHEN @day=31 THEN DAY31 = 'P'               

              END

WHERE empid = @empid AND MONTH = @month AND Year = @Year
END
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: "Can anyone help on this?" - I could change it to a more sensible design where there's one *row* per day, but I don't think that's the kind of help you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF @day = 1
    UPDATE tblattendance 
    SET DAY1 = 'P' 
    WHERE empid = @empid 
    AND MONTH = @month AND Year = @Year
ELSE IF @day = 2
    UPDATE tblattendance 
    SET DAY2 = 'P' 
    WHERE empid = @empid 
    AND MONTH = @month AND Year = @Year
ELSE IF @day = 3
    UPDATE tblattendance 
    SET DAY3 = 'P' 
    WHERE empid = @empid 
    AND MONTH = @month AND Year = @Year
--...
```

---

Or better yet, change your table schema to `empid`, `month`, `year`, `day`, `attendance`. (Or even `empid`, `date`, `attendance`.) This way, you will have one row per day, and queries against the table (no, not just this one) become much easier to manage.

Comment: But, it will make the SP too lengthy, that is why I am thinking.

Comment: @user1532888 Then you should change your table schema as I suggest. It will make life *much* easier than having to deal with 31 different columns.

Comment: @user1532888:- IC. solution is better .. you should think about your table schema first for seamless solution..

Comment: If you have any chance of changing your database design do it now.

Comment: I have incorporated the changes suggested by @lc.

Comment: As suggested by @Ic and @Pranav you could change the schema, and eventually create a view using the [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) function if you need your data in the inital format (one column per day).